# How do i properly map 2 columns to the same entity

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

Forgive me if i'm doing something wrong here, programming or design wise, I just started learning to create spring boot REST api's.

For my data design, I have a User entity.

```
public class User {
   private @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO) Long id;
   private String username;
   private String firstname;
   private String lastname;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "created_by")
   private Set<Ticket> tickets_created = new HashSet<>();

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "modified_by")
   private Set<Ticket> tickets_modified = new HashSet<>();

   //...getters setters
}
```

And then for my other tables lets say I want to store who created the data and who last modified the data. So, lets say I have a table called "Ticket".

```
public class Ticket {
    private @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO) Long id;
    private String subject;
    private String message;
    //.... other columns

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User created_by;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User modified_by;

    //... getters setters
}
```

So this will result in an error saying `Repeated column in mapping for entity...` since I mapped 2 columns to user. I've done a lot of searching but I couldn't find one where this was their case, all I've read about was solved by removing one column since it wasn't really needed or creating a new entity that maps the other 2 entities together, I don't want to do this, this would mean that for every table of mine that would have "created_by" and "modified_by" I would need to create another table to map it to the user table.

Comment: have you had a look into the auditing features that Spring has: https://www.baeldung.com/database-auditing-jpa

Comment: specifically, section 4 (Spring Data JPA) of that link

Comment: @andre thank you, I've tried examples using this, so far i've got dates created/modified working and a hard coded created/modified by. I believe this is what I needed, and now I just need to learn to implement spring security. Feel free to post this as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you had a look into the auditing features that Spring has: baeldung.com/database-auditing-jpa